# Rhino mocks exception with CompositionContainer

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, rhino-mocks

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitListViewModelTests
{
    private CompositionContainer _container;
    private INHDataService _nhDataService;
    private INHUnitOfWork _nhUoW;

    [SetUp]
    [TestCase]
    public void create_container()
    {
        _container = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<CompositionContainer>();
        _nhDataService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<INHDataService>();
        _nhUoW = MockRepository.GenerateMock<INHUnitOfWork>();

        _container.Expect(x => x.GetExportedValue<INHDataService>()).IgnoreArguments().Return(_nhDataService);
    }
}
```

this code throws an exception at `_container.Expect...`.

```
SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : Previous method 'IEnumerator.MoveNext();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.AssertPreviousMethodIsClose()
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.Invocation.Actions.RegularInvocation.PerformAgainst(IInvocation invocation)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RhinoInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IEnumerator`1Proxy15c4de116cb145039cc424d2b9ced840.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Internal.Collections.CollectionServices.GetCardinality[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.CheckCardinality(ImportDefinition definition, IEnumerable`1 exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore(Type type, Type metadataViewType, String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueCore[T](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValue[T](String contractName)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValue[T]()
   at MIB.Test.ViewModels.UnitListViewModelTests.<create_container>b__0(CompositionContainer x) in E:\Work\MIB\MIB.Test\ViewModels\UnitListViewModelTests.cs:line 29#0
   at Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocksExtensions.Expect[T,R](T mock, Function`2 action)
   at MIB.Test.ViewModels.UnitListViewModelTests.create_container() in E:\Work\MIB\MIB.Test\ViewModels\UnitListViewModelTests.cs:line 29#1
```

Edit:
I tried this also but it still throws an exception:

```
_container.Stub(x => x.GetExportedValue<INHDataService>()).IgnoreArguments().Return(_nhDataService);
```

Comment: How is the partially mocked `GetExportedValue` method implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the `CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue()` method is not virtual.

Comment: True, I however gave up trying to mock the `CompositionContainer` and just mocked the exports. Thanks anyway.